# MobileFirst 7.1 - Analytics dumping huge heapdump.phd and core.dmp files on server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

We are using analytics MobileFirst 7.1.0.00.20170505-1403 and we have noticed that analytics server is putting out huge files in GB's for heapdum.phd and core.dmp.

[image]

This is taking away all our San storage. How to turn off this dumping of huge files?

Comment: Please do a javacore/coredump analysis to see what is the problem ? Then we can see it can be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Heap dump is most likely because Analytics server has exhausted all the heap space allocated to it. This could indicate an under sized system without enough resources or a system that is heavily loaded most of the time.

Few quick things that you should keep in mind:

a) Do not install Analytics server and MFP server on the same runtime

b) Configure TTL values for your Analytics entries, so that they are not persisted for ever. Purge the data after an interval

c) In most cases, you will not need all the data to be pumped into your Analytics server. You can control the flow of data into Analytics.
Eg: in production use, limit the amount of event data ( from client) going to Analytics, limit server logs being forwarded to Analytics .

d) Configure circuit breakers to prevent Analytics server from attempting to load too large a data block. This is an Elasticsearch setting:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/index-modules-fielddata.html

To configure circuit breakers and other ES properties, create a elasticsearch yml configuration file. For example, "elasticsearch.yml"

And add the path to this file in your environment entries under the JNDI property:

"analytics/settingspath"

For example:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/settingspath" value="/home/system/elasticsearch.yml" />
```

Comment: Regarding B. I did configure the TTL value for client logs, but I still see client logs being filled in, not sure why Analytics did not get that flag set up correctly. Am I suppose to set it up from server.xml?

Comment: Regarding D where do I set u circuit breaker ? in server.xml.

Comment: Edited the answer to include this.

Comment: do you have any example of elasticsearch.yml

Comment: Vivin is this the other way to set the analytics properties settings<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/indices.fielddata.cache.size" value="20%"/>
      <jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/indices.breaker.fielddata.limit" value="20%"/>

Comment: Elastics search properties should be set in the yml file. Setting in server.xml does not suffice